# Windows 10 laptop doesn't go to sleep when wifi is on

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking, laptop, sleep

I have lenovo ideapad 710s plus laptop with windows 10. When closing the lid, or choosing sleep in windows menu, laptop screen swithces off, but computer remains powered on - lights blincking and cooler is working. If I **switch wifi off** it goes to sleep well.

I tried:

- Upgrading all drivers and downgrading wifi driver
- `powercfg -lastwake` says 0
- `powercfg -devicequery wake_armed` says none
- switching to [allow to sleep when sharing media](https://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/49915-power-options-add-remove-when-sharing-media.html) option

Nothing helped the problem.
How can I detect what prevents my laptop go to sleep?

Comment: You did go to power management in the device properties and disable something along the lines 'allow this device to prevent my computer from sleeping'?

Comment: @El8tedN8te No, but I checked now, and wifi is not allowed to prevent computer from sleeping

Answer (score 0):

Run these steps below:

Method 1: Follow the steps:

> - Press **Windows Key + X**.
> - Select on **Control Panel**.
> - Click on Power Options.  On the left, click on Choose what closing the lid does.  Click on the drop down menu for **When I close the lid** and choose **Sleep** or **Hibernate**.

Method 2: I suggest you to run in-built Power troubleshooter and check. Follow the steps:

> - Press **Windows Key + X**.
> - Click on **Control Panel**.
> - Select **Troubleshooting** on the left pane, click on **View** All.
> - Click on **Power** to run the troubleshooter.

Method 3: If the above method doesn’t help, I would suggest you to reset and restore all of the default Power Plans back with their default settings. Follow the steps.

> - Press **Windows Key + X**.
> - Select **Command Prompt** `(Admin)`.
> - At the command prompt, type `powercfg -restoredefaultschemes`, and then press **ENTER**.
>     At the command prompt, type exit to exit the Command Prompt window.
>     Restart the computer and check with the issue.

Method 4: Lastly I suggest you check your `chipset and video drivers`, try checking for the updates from the manufacturer's website and update all the necessary drivers, i.e the `chipset and video drivers`

Let me know if the issue is resolved or if you require further assistance.

source: [Windows 10 computer](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-other_settings/win-10-computer-wont-lock-or-sleep-when-lid-is/d1214504-d926-4fac-a914-4e4e5d2b1605)

Comment: Thank you for wuick response, unfortunately nothing suggested helped.